# Give console input for List of objects in C#

Tags: c#, list, generics

I want a program to write info about persons to a file in C#...so I have the following class

```
class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

    }
```

And the class that writes to the file is this one:

```
       class Adding
     {
        public static void AddedPersons(List<Person> persons,string path)
        {
            List<string> content = new List<string>();
            
            content.Add("FirstName , LastName");

            foreach (var person in persons)
            {
                content.Add($"{person.FirstName}, {person.LastName}");
            }

            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(path,content);
        }
    }
```

And the main method ...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           
            List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();

           
            string path = @"C:\Users\cosmi\Desktop\Citire\Test.csv";
            
            Elements(persons);
            Adding.AddedPersons(persons, path);
            
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

And the elemnts that I am adding in the List are hard codded in  the following method...

```
 public static void Elements(List<Person> persons)
        {

            persons.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Cosmin", LastName = "Ionut" });
            persons.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Bianca", LastName = "Elena" });
    
        }
```

So what I want is to be able to add those persons as a console input, not hard coded in a method

Comment: Basically, instead of `new Person() { FirstName = "Cosmin", LastName = "Ionut" });` you would read the first name and last name from your CSV into variables and substitute those variables for "Cosmin" and "Ionut".

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I don't think so. I understand he wants to replace the code in `Elements` with some calls to `Console.ReadLine()`. So, Cosmin, you need to define how the user would enter that information. Two words separated by space? Or firstname and lastname separately? And how would the input be complete? The classic "empty to finish"?

Comment: @Andrew I was trying to read them separately,in a 'while' loop  something like this Person.FirstName=Console.Readline(); but I got stuck when coming with an idea to give the posiblity to stop and not continue forever

Comment: Typically you will end with an empty entry, or else you could ask each time a Y/N question to enter or not a new entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a smaller change, I would do this:

```
public static List<Person> GetElements()
{
    List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
    do
    {
        var person = new Person();

        Console.Write("Enter first name: ");
        person.FirstName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter last name: ");
        person.LastName = Console.ReadLine();
        persons.Add(person);

        Console.Write("Press Y to enter another person, other key to finish.");
    } while (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Y);

    return persons;
}
```

The code is pretty straightforward. I wouldn't create the list in `Main` but instead let this method create and populate the list, so all actions related to creating the list are in one place. Furthermore, methods are usually verbs to clearly state what they do. With `void Elements(List<Person>)` you can't guess what it does at all.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I was looking in the first place, to let the user stop the action at the press of a button, but I could't figure out the errors so I gave up on this idea. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to write a method that gets the first and last name from console input and returns a new `Person` object. Below I've added it as a `static` method on the `Person` class.

I also added an instance method called `AsCsvItem` which returns the person in CSV format (`"FirstName, LastName"`), which will come in handy later.

And finally I added a `static` `SaveToFile` method that will save a list of people to the specified file path in Csv format.

Note that these new methods could exist somewhere else, I just put them in the `Person` class for convenience:

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public static Person FromConsoleInput()
    {
        var person = new Person();

        Console.Write("Enter first name: ");
        person.FirstName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter last name: ");
        person.LastName = Console.ReadLine();

        return person;
    }

    public string AsCsvItem()
    {
        return $"{FirstName} , {LastName}";
    }

    public static void SaveToFile(List<Person> people, string path)
    {
        // Create a list with the column headers
        List<string> content = new List<string> {"FirstName , LastName"};

        // Add a line for each person
        content.AddRange(people.Select(person => person.AsCsvItem()));

        // Save it to the file path
        File.WriteAllLines(path, content);
    }
}
```

Then you can just call the `FromConsoleInput` method in a loop to populate a list of people, and the `SaveToFile` method to save them to the csv file. Below I'm using `numPeople` to determine how many people we should add:

```
var numPeople = 2;
var people = new List<Person>();

for (var i = 0; i < numPeople; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Enter person #{i + 1} info:");
    people.Add(Person.FromConsoleInput());
}

Person.SaveToFile(people, @"c:\temp\people.csv");
```